# No sound from guitar

Tags: bridge

I can't get a clear sound from my electric guitar. I've tried to see if my amp was the issue, but it's okay. I can't tell if the brige is the issue since I've tampered with it to place new strings today. What should I do?

Comment: Did it work before you changed the strings? What kind of guitar is it? Is taking it to be repaired by a professional an option?

Comment: Were those new strings explicitly for electric guitar? Because if not, that may be the cause.

Comment: "can't get a clear sound" - can you edit the question and add if there is any sound at all, or just a muffled sound? (I'm thinking if a wire is disconnected inside, or something less serious like a failed volume/tone pot or capacitor.)

Comment: Sometimes the pickup is wired to the bridge, I don't know why, that makes a really quiet muffled sound when it is disconnected

Answer (score 0):

Cord I went thru 3 chords one time before my guitar would play if you have another guitar you can test then you will know if the cord or amp is bad if its the guitar check where it plugs in to see if any of the wires are broken but check cord first